# sending sms to stop a pump using atmega32 and sim300

Tags: microcontroller, gsm

I'm working on a project that has to turn a pump off upon sending an sms to the microcontroller. This code below has to be able to read  and download the message so it can turn the pump off but it is not working. Can someone please check the code and let me know the problem. The microcontroller used is atmega32 and the software to program it is atmel studio 6.1.
    while(1)
    {
        //check_sensor();
        /*uint8_t x=0;

```
    while(GSMWaitForMsg(&id)!=GSM_OK)
    {
        if(x)
        {
            LCDWriteStringXY(10,3,"%3");    //LOVE SYMBOL TILL MSG COMES CHECK MYUTILS.H
            x=0;
        }
        else
        {
            LCDWriteStringXY(10,3,"%4");    //ARROW TO SHOW MESSAGE DOWNLOAD
            x=1;
        }
    }

    LCDWriteStringXY(10,3,"%2");

    _delay_ms(1000);

    //function to read message
    char msg[300];

    int8_t r=GSMReadMsg(id,msg);          //ID=NUMBER MSg=MESSAGE OA=THE REPLY

    if(r==GSM_OK)
    {
        if(strcasecmp(msg,"STOP")==0)       // checking if message read is stop
        {
            PORTC|=(1<<PC7);
            LCDClear();
            LCDWriteStringXY(0,1,"PUMP TURNED OFF");     // displaying on the lcd screen
            RelayOff();                                 // turning the relay off
            _delay_ms(2000);

            goto comehomeboy;       // going back to home

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to give more info here. What shows up on the display? What does "not working" mean more specifically?

Answer (score 0):

The message received for GSM module (on UART of controller) are merely ASCII characters.Mostly there is no NULL(\0) appended to the data.
For strcasecmp() function you need NULL terminated strings as Input.
Please make sure 'msg' array is terminated with NULL.